# CFML system environment variable (OpenBD)

Tags: coldfusion, environment-variables, openbd, cloud-foundry

How do I access the system environment variables in CFML? It is required to read out the CloudFoundry database connectivity settings.

The variable required is "VCAP_SERVICES".

Is there a function for that?

Thanks,

Yvan

Comment: Do you mind if I ask what you hosting environment is?  OS, J2EE server and CF Server will help better get an answer.

Comment: It is an OpenBlueDragon runtime, in the "JavaWeb" environment of CloudFoundry.com

Comment: If you have access to the server itself then try out my comment on Sergii's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following solution seems to work very-very partially on my Ubuntu (it gets far from all variables listed by `env` -- bit this may be fine because JVM just does not get most of these), but it *may* somehow work for you:

```
<cfset properties = createObject("java", "java.lang.System").properties />
<cfdump var="#properties#">
```

Variable you are looking for can be prefixed with `user.`

Comment: It looks like that returns all variables passed into the JVM at the startup time.  What you would have to do, I am assuming, is pass the environment variables you need access to into the JVM.

Comment: IIRC `System.getEnv()` returns a Map of system environment variables. Just verify it is not deprecated ..

Comment: @Leigh Good one, but looks like it is also doesn't return all environment variables available through the shell. Though set of vars is a bit different than `properties`.

Comment: Yes, I am not sure how it works on *nix. On windows there can be some overlapping. So you may end up using properties anyway ;-) http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html